# What is the purpose of the IdentityT transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

While looking through the transformers package, I found this monad transformer called [IdentityT](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Trans-Identity.html).

Although I understand how the Identity monad is used (e.g. `State` is just an alias for `StateT Identity`) and how monad transformers work in general, I have no idea how that relates to `IdentityT`.

Since it's not in the MTL, I'm guessing it was added in there just for completeness and has no practical use. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the linked documentation does say

> This is useful for functions parameterized by a monad transformer.

Though I'm not aware of any situations where this is actually the case. Theoretically if you have a function like `foo :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => t m a -> b` for some useful `b`, then you might want to be able to "dumb it down" to essentially `m a -> b` by using `t = IdentityT`.

But `IdentityT` is to `MonadTrans` what `Identity` is to `Monad`. It is the "pass-through" transformer, as `Identity` is the "pass-through" monad. Just check out the source; it's rather simple. `IdentityT SomeMonad a` should behave identically to `SomeMonad a`, the only difference being the presence of an extra newtype (which, of course, is removed at compile time)

Answer (score 2):

There's a proposed usage here (presumably the origin of IdentityT:
http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2007-June/007563.html

The main use seems to be to allow flexibility at the source code level, e.g. someone can edit the source to xmonad and substitute their own UserT without editing too much code.

I tried to see how that could work for a library - you can use it to provide a placeholder for inserting a monad in the middle of a stack, I'm not sure of a great case for that though. Here's my contrived example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.List
import Control.Monad.Reader

type X m a = StateT Int (m IO) a

something :: (Monad (m IO), MonadIO (m IO)) => (m IO) Int -> X m Int 
something a = do
        x <- lift a
        put (x + 1)

        liftIO $ print x
        return x



listSomething = something $ ListT (mapM return [1,2,3,4])
plainSomething = return 5 :: IdentityT IO Int

main = do 
    x <- runListT (execStateT listSomething 3)
    print x 

    y <- runIdentityT (execStateT plainSomething 3)
    print y

runIdentity $ mapM (return . (+1)) [1..100]
```